# Quarkus Test failure: Cannot invoke "io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext.get(String)" because "context" is null

Tags: mockito, keycloak, quarkus, vert.x

I'm working with Mockito and attempting to authenticate to Keycloak in a JUnit Test.

This worked previous, but has since stopped after an update from Quarkus 3.2.7.Final to 3.6.4 and Keycloak from 22.0.1 to 23.0.4.
*I will caveat, it worked, but sometimes had to be run twice, because the first pass failed.*

The current error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Expected an item event but got a failure: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext.get(String)" because "context" is null

The failure happens at the awaitItem() step

```
@QuarkusTest
class CustomAuthenticationMechanismBasicTest {

    @Inject
    CustomAuthenticationMechanism customAuthenticationMechanism;

    @Inject
    IdentityProviderManager identityProviderManager;

    @Test
    void authenticate() {
        RoutingContext routingContext = Mockito.mock(RoutingContext.class);
        String password = System.getProperty("jdoe-password");
        String b64Auth = Base64.encode(("jdoe:"+password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        HeadersMultiMap headers = new HeadersMultiMap();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic "+b64Auth);
        HttpServerRequest httpServerRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpServerRequest.class);
        Mockito.when(routingContext.request()).thenReturn(httpServerRequest);
        Mockito.when(httpServerRequest.headers()).thenReturn(headers);

        assertEquals("Basic "+b64Auth, routingContext.request().headers().get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION));
        UniAssertSubscriber<SecurityIdentity> securityIdentityUniAssertSubscriber =
                customAuthenticationMechanism.authenticate(routingContext, identityProviderManager)
                .subscribe().withSubscriber(UniAssertSubscriber.create()).awaitItem();
```

I have multiple tenants set up for Keycloak for the different authentication grant types with the default oidc-client grant.type = client and a separate tenant "basic" for grant.type=password.

Last note, the on CustomAuthenticationMechanism. It's a custom authentication that I am experimenting with to refresh offline tokens to access tokens, without the extra OIDC calls by the client.

Any suggestions?